# Android context button blocks back button functionality

Tags: android, navigation, contextmenu, back

I have a problem in all my activities, when I press the back button it works properly, but when I press the context menu button before, nothing happens when I press back.
I am talking about the phone buttons, not the toolbar icon for back navigation. Has anyone ever dealt with this?

EDIT:
No menu shows, onPrepareOptionsMenu() is removed, the phone vibrates when I press back but no action.
I see that if I inflate a menu, it worsk properly after the first back that closes te popup.

I see that this happens only if I set the toolbar with setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: Is there a context menu that pops up? If so, the back button closes the context menu, which is normal behavior. If you see no context menu, perhaps you still have an empty context menu defined.

Comment: OnPrepareOptionsMenu() is removed, I tried to return false to it but no luck. What do you suggest?
No popup shows,and I can hit back as much as I want, it does nothing.

Comment: Do you override onBackPressed()?

Comment: onBackPressed() is not overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have nearly the same problem, this is my case:

- AppCompatActivity with toolbar set with setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
- I'm using a navigation Drawer (dont know if this can affect)
- onBackPressed() is overriden to prompt logout dialog

All works fine until i press the device menu button, then the app begins to ignore the back button.

This is what i have seen after pressing the device menu button

- The method onBackPressed() is not called after this
- If you set an onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event), it receives the event (and you can check that de keyCode is the same as KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)

I don't know why the onBackPressed stops from being called, tried without overriding onBackPressed and onKeyUp and the problem is still the same.

I know this is not the best solution, but to fix this problem i'm using the next code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, I was trying with dispatch key event and that was not working acordingly.